# Reading a data from file gives error says the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, file, apache-poi

Hello Guys I have made a xlsx file in the mentioned location as in figure:

[image]

and I have a code as below:-

```
package com.nischal;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class FileRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       File src = new File("D:\\Nischal.xlsx");
       FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
       XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
       XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);
               
     System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
     System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

      } 
}
```

Though there is nothing wrong it always yields the error called: (The system cannot find the file specified)

Image of the Error:

[image]

Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Try to put a fie to some folder (not to root of the drive)

Comment: I have tried that too. But it didn't work, Please if you could provide me few more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to cast variable name "fis" to string while sending as parameter to XSSFWorkbook;

```
XSSFWorkbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(String.valueOf(fis));
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was there when I have created a file i.e I have given the file Name is Nischal.xslx but it is not proper format I have to give file name only Nischal and select extension as .xslx. And Now finally it works.**

**See Now I have changed my renamed my file as**

[image]

The Working code is same as above.